# MetaMask showing 'transfer' method - How do I switch it to 'Smart Contract Interaction'?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, metamask

I have a simple transaction set up to send 100 of my ERC20 token to a certain address. Please see the code below:

```
if (window.ethereum) {
   
   await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
   window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

let tokenAddress = "my_token_address";
let toAddress = "desitnation_address";
let fromAddress = accountBin;
// Use BigNumber
let decimals = 18;
//let amount = 100;
let minABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_initialSupply","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
// Get ERC20 Token contract instance
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, tokenAddress);
// calculate ERC20 token amount
//let value = amount.mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
// call transfer function
contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, web3.utils.toWei('100')).send({from: fromAddress})

.on('transactionHash', function(hash){


console.log('Payment successful', hash);
```

My problem is, the transaction is set up correctly but MetaMask displays the transaction as a 'Transfer' when I would like it to display 'Smart Contract Interaction' This way users can't modify the transaction amount via MetaMask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Metamask recognizes the transaction as a Transfer is that the function selector is a common and easily reproduced string. For example, according to [solidity-by-example](https://solidity-by-example.org/function-selector/), "`transfer(address,uint256)`" is encoded into `0xa9059cbb`. Metamask and other services like Etherscan must associate all function selectors named `0xa9059cbb` is to `transfer`

[image]
^^transfer is recognized by metamask!!
[image]
^^unusualFunctionSelectorName is just a contract interaction!!

Your solution is to name your function something else. Also, I don't see why users could modify the transaction amount anyways. You might be thinking of the gas. Metamask doesn't support that I think.

Comment: Just a note for your otherwise good answer: renaming the function name makes the contract non-ERC20 compatible. A better alternative (if the user really doesn't want to use the default `transfer` function) would be to add a new custom function which just forwards the call to the `transfer` function.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I completely forgot about being compliant with the ERC20 standard. Good thinking

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying.

I've tried your method and it works great but I've run into another issue. Now the value of the transaction is not showing up in the MetaMask transaction.

Any ideas? Cheers